# Azure SQL Server : There are multiple execution plans created if the Stored Procedure Option (Keep Plan) is set

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using the Azure SQL Server Database.

It seems that the Azure SQL Server Database creates multiple execution plans regardless of whether Option (Keep Plan) is selected.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllCustomers
@varX DataType-Y...
AS
    SELECT .....
    Where ....
    Order By ....
    Option (Keep Plan)
GO;
```

[image]

As per the definition:

> KEEP PLAN
> Forces the query optimizer to relax the estimated recompile threshold for a query. The estimated recompile threshold is the point at which a query is automatically recompiled when the estimated number of indexed column changes have been made to a table by running UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT statements. Specifying KEEP PLAN makes sure that a query will not be recompiled as frequently when there are multiple updates to a table.

Any reasons for creating multiple execution plans? Is it fine to go with Option (Keep Plan)?

Comment: *keep plan* reduces query recompilations, a query only has a single cached execution plan (afaik) - until SQL Server 2022.

Comment: Even I was expecting only a single cached execution plan but I see at least 2 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen image in your question is from the query store. This QS report shows a history of the plans, not just the current cached one, so you may see multiple plans for the same query.

Comment: Does it just not have a single execution plan since I opted to keep the plan with Option (Keep Plan)? Why does it have multiple plan in the QS?

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan, the `KEEP PLAN` hint reduces compilations but you may still get a different plan each compilation. Perhaps you are thinking of `KEEP FIXED PLAN`?

Comment: Thank you. When would the SQL Server create a new execution plan with KEEP PLAN is set? I know the parameter sniffing will come into the play. But, would like to confirm.

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan, with or without `KEEP PLAN`, recompilation occurs based on changes to the underlying tables. The difference is the a higher threshold with the hint so recompiles occur less frequently.

Comment: There can be small differences in the plan identity - it is not a perfect metric nor is it intended to be.  Those plans may be functionally identical.  There are some cases where you can get different plan hashes for roughly the same plan.  So, please don't look at the query store and make an assumption that some exact same physical plan exists or does not.  Keep plan only has to do with recompile behavior.  Generally you should not even use it.

Comment: How do I find the current cached execution plan? and How does SQL SERVER know the current cached plan can not be used for the current running query.

Comment: This query will get the current cached plan for the proc: `SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName, OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ProdNAme, qp.query_plan FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS ps CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qp WHERE ps.database_id = DB_ID() AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SelectAllCustomers');`. A cached plan can be used for the same query until it's voided due to schema changes.